# Get field value from inline entity form (multiple values)

Tags: entities

Here is the situation:

1- I'm creating a content type.
2- I have an inline entity form (Multiple Values) in my content type.
3- My inline entity form asks a number (integer).
4- In my content type, I have a "computed field" too, that has to add integers given from entity nodes created in inline entity form into itself.

Please tell me how to get values from inline entities (multiple values).

Is there any "array" solution to get all of them?